# Installing hexSticker package for creating a hexagonal logo in R 4.2.3

Tags: r, package

I am trying to create a visually appealing hexagonal logo for my R package. After doing some research, I came across the hexSticker package, which provides useful instructions for creating such logos. However, when I attempted to install the package using the command `install.packages("hexSticker")`, I encountered an error stating that the package is not available for my current version of R (4.2.3).

I would like to know if there is an updated version of the hexSticker package compatible with R 4.2.3. If not, are there any alternative options or other packages that I can use to achieve the same result?

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried from github? `# install.package("remotes")   #In case you have not installed it.
remotes::install_github("GuangchuangYu/hexSticker")`